# How to create sub samples of a dataset with data gaps

Tags: r

Separate Tide data into smaller datasets

The desired outcome is to determine if the dataset contain NAs, if yes, separate the dataset into multiple datasets omitting the sections void of water level data (height..ft.). Data includes time..min. in 15 minute increments starting at 0 and associated water levels

My goal is to automate the process of creating sub samples of data.

I'm brand new to R, so very appreciative of any and all help!

```
install.packages(dplyr)
library(dplyr)

fiftn.min <- read.table('C:/Temp/WL.csv',header=T,sep=',')

# View rows where height is NA (many missing rows of data)
fiftn.min[is.na(fiftn.min$height..ft.),]

# Plot to visually inspect data, plot shows three distinct complete sets of data
# and two data gaps.
plot(fiftn.min, pch = 20, col = "deepskyblue4", cex = .05,
     main = "ENTIRE SAMPLE",
     xlab = "Time (Min) 15 Minute Increments", 
     ylab = "Water Level (ft)")

# Inspect the table to investigate instances of NAs
# Visual inspection of the table shows that data gaps begin at time..min. =
# 124560 and time..min. = 193545
View(fiftn.min[is.na(fiftn.min$height..ft.),])

# Use the filer function to separate the segments of data without observations

# Manually inspect to determine the range of data sub samples 

par(mfrow = c(3,1))
s1 <- filter(fiftn.min, time..min. < 124560)
plot(s1, pch = 20, col = "deepskyblue4", cex = .05,
     main = "SAMPLE 1",
     xlab = "Time (Min) 15 Minute Increments", 
     ylab = "Water Level (ft)")

s2<- filter(fiftn.min, time..min. >132000 & time..min. <193545)
plot(s2, pch = 20, col = "deepskyblue4", cex = .05,
     main = "SAMPLE 2",
     xlab = "Time (Min) 15 Minute Increments", 
     ylab = "Water Level (ft)")

s3 <- filter(fiftn.min, time..min. > 204525)
plot(s3, pch = 20, col = "deepskyblue4", cex = .05,
     main = "SAMPLE 3",
     xlab = "Time (Min) 15 Minute Increments", 
     ylab = "Water Level (ft)")
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0GkR.png)

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow. Is imputing the `NA` data not an option?

Comment: Ideally I would like to eliminate the data with NA values and have separate subsets of complete data. This has to be completed for an entire year of water level data, hence the need to automate. Right now it's a cut and paste exercise in Excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure this is what you're looking for - a simple example with data might be helpful.

I made up some example data including a `time` and `height` column, setting some values of `height` to missing (`NA`):

```
library(dplyr)

set.seed(123)

df <- data.frame(
  time = 1:20,
  height = sample(20)
)

df$height[c(5:7, 13:15)] <- NA
```

The resultant data.frame looks like this:

```
   time height
1     1     15
2     2     19
3     3     14
4     4      3
5     5     NA
6     6     NA
7     7     NA
8     8     11
9     9      5
10   10      4
11   11     18
12   12      9
13   13     NA
14   14     NA
15   15     NA
16   16      7
17   17     16
18   18      1
19   19      8
20   20     13
```

Then, you can add a column to indicate where a dataset would start (when a value of `height` is available, but the previous row `height` was missing):

```
df$start <- !is.na(df$height) & is.na(lag(df$height))
```

Then, you can create groups to enumerate the subsets of data:

```
df$group <- cumsum(df$start)
```

And finally use `split` to split the data.frame up (the final result is a `list`):

```
df |>
  na.omit(height) |>
  split(~group)
```

**Output**

```
$`1`
  time height start group
1    1     15  TRUE     1
2    2     19 FALSE     1
3    3     14 FALSE     1
4    4      3 FALSE     1

$`2`
   time height start group
8     8     11  TRUE     2
9     9      5 FALSE     2
10   10      4 FALSE     2
11   11     18 FALSE     2
12   12      9 FALSE     2

$`3`
   time height start group
16   16      7  TRUE     3
17   17     16 FALSE     3
18   18      1 FALSE     3
19   19      8 FALSE     3
20   20     13 FALSE     3
```

Note: you can assign the above to a second data.frame, and then extract a specific group/subset if needed. For example, if assigned to `df2` and wanted group 2, could use `df2[[2]]`.

**Edit**: For the follow up question regarding plots, you can try the following:

First, store your result as `my_list`:

```
my_list <- df |>
  na.omit(height) |>
  split(~group)
```

Then, you can create a custom function, `plot_fun`, for all your plots, specifying that you'll use the 1st 2 columns of data. The function also can include `num` as an argument to specify which sample.

```
plot_fun <- function(dat, num) {
  plot(dat[,1:2], pch = 20, col = "deepskyblue4", cex = .05,
       main = paste("SAMPLE", num),
       xlab = "Time (Min) 15 Minute Increments", 
       ylab = "Water Level (ft)")
}
```

Then, you can create all your plots using `mapply`:

```
mapply(plot_fun, dat = my_list, num = names(my_list))
```

Also, you may want to take a look at `ggplot2` for future plots.

Comment: This looks like exactly what I'm looking for. I'm going to try to implement your example on my data. Thank you for such a thorough response! I appreciate you recommendations about the help request as well. I'm brand new to R and stack overflow so any guidance is absolutely helpful.

Comment: ```df |>
  na.omit(height) |>
  split(~group)

Comment: What version of R are you using? That would require 4.10 with the new pipe. You can make separate statements instead such as `na.omit(df$height)` and `split(df, df$group)` ... you might need intermediate storage of data.frame results (or overwriting)...

Comment: Just a couple of questions. When running your code and using View() to see dataframe 'df' after line: 'df$start <- !is.na(df$height) & is.na(lag(df$height))' start column reads FALSE in many instances when the time and height data is present.

Comment: Additionally the last step is giving me an error: "Error in unique.default(x, nmax = nmax) : unique() applies only to vectors"                                                                                                
  df %>%
  na.omit(height) %>%
  split(~group)

Comment: for the first issue - the start should only be present if height is available, but previous row was missing...in those instances where height data is present, is the row above it missing?

Comment: also note that `start` should only be `TRUE` for only 1 row in the beginning of a section of data, not all of the rows of data within a section...most of the rows should be `FALSE` except for the first row in a group...

Comment: Thank for the clarity about ```start``` and ```TRUE```. I understand the logic now for assigning a value. Also, you are correct. I have an older version and the new commands work for both your script and my data. Now I just need to write these outputs to a .csv file. Thanks so much for the help, this is an amazing community and has already helped me learn so much.

Comment: Last question if you have the time. Is there a way to automatically generate plots for all of the sub groups? It sounds like since they are lists, I will first need to convert to a dataframe?

Comment: @Michelle Please see edited answer which allows for plots from the list. No need to do any conversions. Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you.